# SDF text rendering in perspective projection

Tags: fonts, opengl-es, webgl

I'm using SDF technique http://www.valvesoftware.com/publications/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_AlphaTestedMagnification.pdf to render text in WebGL. I made SDF texture of font, generate BMFont text metrics and display the text using simple fragment shader:

```cpp
        precision mediump float;
        uniform sampler2D u_texture;        
        varying vec2 vUv;

        float aastep(float value) {
          float afwidth = 0.1;
          return smoothstep(0.5 - afwidth, 0.5 + afwidth, value);
        }

        void main(void)
        {            
            vec4 texColor = texture2D(u_texture, vUv);
            float alpha = aastep(texColor.a);
            gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, alpha);            
        }
```

I have a problem with `afwidth` value in `aastep` function. afwidth simply defines blurring of font borders. If it is small then faraway text looks ugly. If large - text close to me looks ugly. So the questions is how to calculate afwidth in fragment shader?

PS: I have a formula to calculate it using GL_OES_standard_derivatives:

```cpp
float afwidth = length(vec2(dFdx(value), dFdy(value))) * 0.70710678118654757;
```

But my hardware do not support this extension. So I think I need to calculate it based on `gl_FragCoord` and transform matrix.

Comment: Link to Valve paper @ 11-2020:  https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/valve/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_AlphaTestedMagnification.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just checking but are you sure your hardware does not support `OES_standard_derivatives`? http://webglstats.com makes it appear that's unlikely.

In WebGL you have to enable OES_standard_derivatives to use it.

```
ext = gl.getExtention("OES_standard_derivatives");
if (!ext) {
  // alert("no OES standard derivatives") or fallback to other technique
}
```

Then in your shader you have to turn it on

```
// at top of fragment shader
#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
```

[Run this test to check if they work on your system](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/extensions/oes-standard-derivatives.html). If you get a very short result about them not existing then you're correct they don't exist. If you get a lots of results then they do exist and you just have not enabled them in your program

Answer (score 2):

One might try to create a simple approximation of distance-to-camera, based on `gl_FragCoord.w = 1.0 / gl_Position.w`:

```cpp
    float aastep(float value)
    {
          float distanceToCamera = 1.0 / gl_FragCoord.w;
          float afwidth = 0.1 * distanceToCamera;
          return smoothstep(0.5 - afwidth, 0.5 + afwidth, value);
    }
```

You will likely need to adjust the constant `0.1` to your liking.

Comment: That is exactly what I did, but I sure it's wrong because If I change for example FOV of camera I will need to change this constant, so i should somehow calculate its value, that is my question about